# How to add androidx library(appcompat) to a unity project?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

How to add the `Androidx library` (appcompat) to a `Unity` project?

I try to add the `appcompat.aar` taken from [maven google](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.appcompat:appcompat) in my folder asset>Plugins>Android

But I have this error in my debugger

```
2023-04-22 14:46:21.936 8819 8857 Error Unity AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity;
2023-04-22 14:46:21.936 8819 8857 Error Unity java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity;
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I would use the [External Dependency Manager](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) and be sure to enable the Use Jetifier option to try and update any legacy plugins to use their AndroidX counterpart.